# Java: why doesn't deadlock happen when in this simple example with two threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, deadlock

I have this code:

```
public class UsbDrive extends HardDrive {
    private Date lastUpdate;

    private void updateDate()  {
        lastUpdate = new Date();
    }

    public synchronized void cutAndPaste(UsbDrive other, int originAddress, int destAddress)  {
        byte[] data = read(originAddress);

        boolean success = other.write(data, destAddress);
        if (success) {
            erase(originAddress);
            updateDate();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Write failed!");
        }
    }
}
```

```
class HardDrive  {
...
public synchronized byte[] read(int address)  {...}
public synchronized boolean write(byte[] data, int address)  {...}
    public synchronized void erase(int address)  {...}
...
```

I'm trying to simulate a deadlock

```
public class Main  {
 private static UsbDrive usb1 = new UsbDrive();
    private static UsbDrive usb2 = new UsbDrive();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws  Exception  {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadA());
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadB());

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

        thread1.join();
        thread2.join();
    }

    static class ThreadA implements Runnable  {
        @Override
        public void run()  {
            try  {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
            catch (Exception e)  {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            synchronized (usb1) {
                usb1.cutAndPaste(usb2, 1, 2);
            }
        }
    }

    static class ThreadB implements Runnable  {
        @Override
        public void run()  {
            synchronized (usb2) {
                usb2.cutAndPaste(usb1, 1, 2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However deadlock doesn't happen - why? ThreadA calls method `cutAndPaste()` locked on `usb1`, while inside that method `write()` is called which is locked on `usb2`
Shouldn't deadlock occur?
How should I change the code to trigger deadlock?

I get this output:

```
reading data
Erasing data
reading data
Erasing data
```

Comment: Probably by the time your second thread starts, the first one has finished already?

Comment: @schneida I edited the post: I added Thread.sleep() which quaranteed ThreadB started running at the same time, but deadlock didn't happen

Comment: All your thread.sleep does is let thread 2 complete before 1 even starts...

Comment: If you really want to make resource contention happen, try a for loop that continuously accesses your data in both threads. Programs operate on much faster scales than people, it won't take anywhere close to 5 whole seconds for the second thread to be created, ran, and thrown away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a race condition that decides whether the deadlock happens or not as far as I can see, one good option to make the deadlock more likely to happen is a loop, but an easier option might be to insert `Thread.sleep(5000);` between `byte[] data = read(originAddress);` and `boolean success = other.write(data, destAddress);` in `UsbDrive::cutAndPaste`. **EDIT:** And remove the existing `Thread.sleep(5000);`.

**EDIT:** Clarified answer.

**EDIT2:** I just ran the code with the changes, and it indeed induces a deadlock now:

```java
import java.util.Date;

public class Main  {
 private static UsbDrive usb1 = new UsbDrive();
    private static UsbDrive usb2 = new UsbDrive();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws  Exception  {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadA());
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadB());

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

        thread1.join();
        thread2.join();
    }

    static class ThreadA implements Runnable  {
        @Override
        public void run()  {
            synchronized (usb1) {
                usb1.cutAndPaste(usb2, 1, 2);
            }
        }
    }

    static class ThreadB implements Runnable  {
        @Override
        public void run()  {
            synchronized (usb2) {
                usb2.cutAndPaste(usb1, 1, 2);
            }
        }
    }
}

class UsbDrive extends HardDrive {
    private Date lastUpdate;

    private void updateDate()  {
        lastUpdate = new Date();
    }

    public synchronized void cutAndPaste(UsbDrive other, int originAddress, int destAddress)  {
        byte[] data = read(originAddress);

        try  {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch (Exception e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        boolean success = other.write(data, destAddress);
        if (success) {
            erase(originAddress);
            updateDate();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Write failed!");
        }
    }
}

class HardDrive  {
    public synchronized byte[] read(int address)  {return new byte[]{};}
    public synchronized boolean write(byte[] data, int address)  {return true;}
    public synchronized void erase(int address)  {}
}
```

Comment: Race condition? Not a deadlock? Thanks, I'll try the sleep

Comment: I need a deadlock to occur, not a race condition  ; (

Comment: I apologize, I meant that it is a race condition whether the deadlock happens or not, I will clarify the answer. By removing the existing `Thread.sleep(5000);` and inserting it the other place, the deadlock should become much more likely to happen, such that you will not need a loop.

Comment: I've thought about it - is the `synchronize` in the `run` methods necessary? Those that lock on `usb1` and `usb2`? Should the `synchronized` in the `read, write, erase` methods be enough?

Comment: @parsecer That's extremely basic. You ought to be able to figure that out yourself. How could you get to the point where you are "trying to simulate a deadlock" without understanding that or be able to figure that out? Is this homework or a test?

Comment: I think I understand it, I just wanted to be sure. I removed all synchronize apart from the ones on the read, write and erase and the deadlock still happened - as expected